# ECSAgent AwsvpcAdditionalLocalRoutes option

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ecs

I am in the process of setting up a new ECS windows cluster in AWS.
While reading [this](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonECS/latest/developerguide/launch_window-container_instance.html) piece of documentation I came across the `AwsvpcAdditionalLocalRoutes` option, but it is unclear to me what this option is for. I didn't manage to find any more info about it after some online searches.

Can someone explain why this option is available and describe the use-cases where it is meant to be used?

Answer (score 0):

There seems little information for this option.

[This docs](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonECS/latest/developerguide/ecs-agent-config.html) says as follows and more understandable.

> ECS_AWSVPC_ADDITIONAL_LOCAL_ROUTES Example values: ["10.0.15.0/24"]
>
> Default value on Linux: []
>
> Default value on Windows: []
>
> In awsvpc network mode, traffic to these prefixes is routed via the
> host bridge instead of the task elastic network interface.

My understanding is that this option is used when you want to use `bridge` mode for specific ip address as well as `awsvpc` mode. Use case is for example you want to set up daynamic port mapping for the ip address. (Only `bridge` mode support dynamic port mapping. [ref](https://aws.amazon.com/premiumsupport/knowledge-center/dynamic-port-mapping-ecs/?nc1=h_ls))